# Swing: Is there a simple way to make 1 component ignore the layout manager?

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

I have a JPanel with one component that I want to place in an absolute sense, whereas the rest of the components are placed according to a layout manager.

Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: yes, nothing special, just multilplay JPanels (basic stuff how to mixing LayoutManagers in one Container), f.e. 1st. that's contains only null layout, and other with some of LayoutManagers

Comment: Still waiting for a reply or a SSCCE to further qualify the question. If the question is important enough to be asked, the least you can do is reply to the people who took the time to respond.

Comment: @camickr -- WTF? Not everyone spends every day on StackOverflow, especially when the weather gets nice. I have a job with work that takes priority over any SO questions I ask. When I have time, I try to do the best job I can at asking and answering questions. Sometimes an SSCCE is beyond my time and/or ability, as the questions I ask usually aren't that simple. Your answers have been helpful, and I usually upvote them, and it peeves me that you can't wait more than a few days without posting a comment that implies that my efforts on SO are substandard.

Comment: @Jason S, I"ve noticed that you have been back to SO several times during the last 5 days. In fact you've asked 6 other questions during that span. So my point is if you have time to continually ask questions (and accept several of them), then you had time to look at and comment on this question as well. So yes it does peeve me when you apparently completely ignore all 3 responses that where given to you in this posting given you prompt replies to other questions.

Comment: @camickr -- I don't ignore them. I'm very busy, and I have to triage. You can't decide whether another person who isn't you has enough time to do something. If you can't deal, then don't bother answering my questions anymore. Suit yourself.

Comment: @Jason S, Don't be so selfish, the forum is not about you. We are all very busy and only have limited time to answer questions. The assumption when we answer a question is that the question is important to you NOW, not next week. If you know the question isn't important or you won't be able to repsond to it for 5 days, then don't post the question for 5 days or at least have the courtesy to mention that you won't be able to respond for a certain time frame. They we can also manage our time effectively and give help to those in more current need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you saying you want a component painted over top of all the other components? If so then you would need to use a JLayeredPane.

Why don't you post a SSCCE that demonstrates what you want to do?

You can add components to a frame as you would do normally and make the frame visible. Then you can add this random component and use setBounds on the component. As long as you don't revalidate() the panel or resize the frame we will be able to see how you intend to position this component relative to all the other components.

Answer (score 3):

You might also want to look at [`OverlayLayout`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/OverlayLayout.html), seen [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/AtestoftheOverlayLayoutmanagerallowingexperimentation.htm). For some reason it's excluded from the conventional [gallery](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html), but it may be of interest.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with only needing one JPanel using MigLayout